# Using :target for data attribute in CSS

Tags: css, target, custom-data-attribute

I have an anchor that links to an element using data-attributes for which need special styles when targeted.

**My logic**

```
span[data-anchor="my-data"]:target {
    /* styles */
}

<a href="#my-data">anchor</a>

<span data-anchor="my-data">My Data</span>
```

I'm using Shortcodes Ultimate (WP)
https://gndev.info/shortcodes-ultimate/

Answer (score 0):

:target works on the currently active anchor
it doesn't really need a selector

try something like this:

html:

```
<a href="#my-data">anchor</a>
<span id="my-data">My Data</span>
```

css:

```
:target {
    background-color: red;
}
```

see a working example here-
https://jsfiddle.net/0fkh8n09/